# PostgresSQL group by returning multiple cells with same value in group by column

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a list that shows the total amount of each food item. I have got the data that I want, however, it displays multiple cells with the same value in the ingredient column which is included in the group by.

I have tried rebuilding the script but this is as close as I can get.

```
SELECT  "recipeingredients"."ingredient", 
("recipeingredients"."amountperservekg" * SUM("transactionGC"."Unit_Qty_Sold")) as "Total Ingredient"
FROM public.recipemain
left join "recipelinkingpos" on "recipemain"."recipename"  = "recipelinkingpos"."sendrecipe"
left join "recipeingredients" on "recipemain"."recipeid" = "recipeingredients"."recipeid"
left join "transactionGC" on "recipelinkingpos"."Product_Name" = "transactionGC"."Product_Name"
where 
ingredient is not null 
and 
date_trunc('week',"transactionGC"."Date/Time") 
between (now()- interval '8 days') and (now()-interval '1 days')  
group by 
"recipeingredients"."amountperservekg",
"recipeingredients"."ingredient"
order by "recipeingredients"."ingredient" asc;
```

Results from the above script. I want to have only one instance of each ingredient.

```
Agar Agar           0.00018750000890577212
Almond, Slivered    0.021875000093132257
Anchovies           0.14999999664723873
Avocado                 2.8500000424683094
Bacon                   1.529999965801835
Bacon                   4.139999907463789
Banana                  0.11999999731779099
Barramundi          2.1600000858306885
Basil, Fresh            1.5199999660253525
Basil, Fresh            0.04800000227987766
Basil, Fresh            0.1599999964237213
Basil, Fresh            0.44999998807907104
Bay Leaves          0.005500000261235982
Bean Shoots         0.6000000089406967
Bean Shoots         0.3799999915063381
Beans, Green            2.1599999517202377
Beef, Rib Eye           5.200000077486038
Beef, Rump End          1.4000000208616257
Beef, Striploin         0.35999999195337296
Beef, Striploin         3.0000001192092896
```

Comment: why are you using left join ? why not inner join?

Comment: I have tried changing between the two with no change in results. I will change now. The main reason I suppose is lack of understanding.

Comment: " I want to have only one instance of each ingredient." - so why are you grouping by "amountperservekg" as well?

Comment: I didn't want to but the script will not run

Comment: SQL Error [42803]: ERROR: column "recipeingredients.amountperservekg" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
  Position: 45

Comment: did the values matched if you do a sum of ingredient manually from the result?
Basil, Fresh            1.5199999660253525
Basil, Fresh            0.04800000227987766
Basil, Fresh            0.1599999964237213
Basil, Fresh            0.44999998807907104

Comment: Sorry I am not sure exactly what you mean. If I SUM("recipeingredients"."amountperservekg") the results are not what I want. If I add the results together, I get the answer I want. The correct answer is achieved by adding the results from total ingredient

Comment: I added an aggregate function to "recipeingredients"."amountperservekg" because different recipes have different amounts of the ingredient and different Unit_Qty_Sold the result isn't correct.

Comment: The first result is expected, the second occurs with Avg("recipeingredients"."amountperservekg") 2.177999953 :
2.062784765

Comment: Apparently you have different values for `amountperservekg` for each value of `ingredient`  - from what you have posted, I would assume that what you indeed want is `sum(amountperservekg * Unit_Qty_Sold)`. But as you said you don't want that (or at least don't expect that). Then please add some sample **input** data that shows different values of the `amountperservekg` and how you want to deal with that.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name This is the solution. Thank you very much